# create a container struct hold two field, referencing from one to another

Tags: rust

The situation is a bit of confusing.
I'm trying to use `odbc-api` to query result from odbc datasources, and wrapped the functions into ffi.

odbc-api defines following structs as below,

```rust
struct Envirnoment {...}
struct Connection<'c> {...}


impl Envirnoment {
    pub fn connect_with_connection_string(
        &self,
        connection_string: &str,
    ) -> Result<Connection<'_>, Error> {...}
}
```

For my situation, on the C side, `create_connection` is called to return a connection handler defines in rust.

```
#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn create_connection(c_str: *const c_char) -> *mut Connection<'static> {
    let env = Environment::new().unwrap();
    let conn = env.connect_with_connection_string(CStr::from_ptr(c_str).to_str().unwrap()).unwrap();
    Box::into_raw(Box::new(conn))
}
```

The compiler returns error as below.

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `env`
  --> odbc-demo/src/main.rs:37:5
   |
36 |     let conn = env.connect_with_connection_string(CStr::from_ptr(c_str).to_str().unwrap()).unwrap();
   |                --- `env` is borrowed here
37 |     Box::into_raw(Box::new(conn))
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

The lifetime of Connection cannot be resolved, since `env` is dropped when function returns. How can I bind `env` and `connection` into a single struct as a handler exposes to ffi? Is `std::pin` the solution? How to define the lifetime of connection in the handler struct?

Furthermore, I'd like to make `env` into a global static Arc object, so that I can create multiple connection from the single env.

```
lazy_static!{
    static ref ENV: Arc<Envirnoment> = Arc::new(Envirnoment::new().unwrap());
}
```

Then how to define the handler struct?

My expected handler looks like

```
#[repr(C)]
struct ConnectionHandler{
    env: Arc<Envirnoment>,
    conn: Connection<'_>,
}
```

##### Update:

My expected handler is to capture a lifetime bounded object and the bounded object, on stack, to extend the whole lifetime and transfer the ownership to ffi. I think `std::pin` should work as expect, since the expected handler works like an async function.

After reconsidering the whole design of my FFI implements, my design turns out that the connection object maintains in (green) thread, and use `std::sync::mpsc` to transfer the control to ffi.

Comment: Hi LvLng! Welcome :) Could you share any error / compilation messages you're getting? Please can you do this by editing your Question so that it's easy for users coming across your question to see.

Comment: I think you're on the right track here. What error do you get if you use your global ENV instead of env inside create_connection? What's the purpose of ConnectionHandler? I'm curious, why do you want to call from C to Rust given that ODBC is a C API? (why not use it directly?)

Comment: @battlmonstr I'm using arrow-odbc to retrive arrow tables from various backended DBMS. Sharing a connection is the very first step. After update of using `mpsc`, problems are not all solved. Assuming the connection is shared over queries. Then how can I spawn a sub-thread to exeucte query on the shared connection. The the problem turns back to how to defince a wrapped struct with all references captured, so that the object is not lifetime bounded.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct)

Comment: If your `ENV` is available globally, then your connection handler can simply have a `Connection<'static>`

Comment: Hi author of `odbc-api` here. Just stumbled over this. You can create multiple connections with static lifetime from a `lazy_static` environment. No Arc needed. I also used a C-Interface in `arrow-odbc-py` to create the Python binding for `arrow-odbc` in case you want to take a look.